# Sqoop merge throw InvalidRecordException:Parquet/Avro schema mismatch. Avro field 'ENTITYID' not found

Tags: merge, sqoop

Sqoop merge throw InvalidRecordException : Parquet/Avro schema mismatch. Avro field 'ENTITYID' not found.
Source data and target data are in parquet format when target data scheme has a extra column then Sqoop merge run into this issue.

Sqoop version:1.4.7.7.1.7.1063-8

Is there anyway to resolve this.